# If I use Storyboards will I still have to create xibs for backwards compatibility?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

This is a general iOS 5+/4 question:

If I make my app using storyboards, it won't work on pre iOS 5 devices (iphone/ipod touch).

Apple requires that an app targeted for iOS 5+ must still be compatible with iOS 4.

So basically, I'm better off just starting out with a non-storyboard app (ie xib)?
Put another way, if I'll end up having to create xibs anyways, then why use storyboards to begin with?

While storyboards are pretty and can help organize the layout, it still seems like more work in the end. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct, you cannot use storyboard on pre iOS 5. so if you are thinking of supporting iOS 4.3 then you better work with xibs from the begining

Comment: Thanks, so basically, if the app is targeted towards an ipod touch, then use xibs as gens 1 & 2 don't support iOS 5?